# Wifi stopped working after Ubuntu update on Dell Latitude d620

Tags: wireless, updates

My wifi stopped working after I got the new ubuntu update..ive tried a few of these codes already but im not making any progress. Can someone just help me start at step 1 and get this thing fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Network Connections panel and disable the auto connect of the wifi connection you used before. Then create manually a new connection. After reboot you could use the wifi again.

Answer (score 0):

D620 uses Broadcom chips, it's the usual problem with these chips
First you need to show the output of `lspci -nn` as you have to know the exact chip you using, then get ready to use a cable to get connected to your router

Also you may want to check this link

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless